# I want to put text inside of rock and have an object drop on it and make the rock crumble leaving only the text

Tags: particles, physics

I'm using Blender 2.76 and I have the text inside of a rock textured cube but I want to make a bottle come down crash on it to crumble the rock so that the text is now visible. I did the wood chipper text tutorial so I have a basic grasp of how to do the text within a cube and perform the particles and physics just not sure how I could replicate the bottle smashing down and have it break open and crumble down leaving the bottle resting on the text.

Comment: Take a look at the fratcure modifier build http://df-vfx.de/fracturemodifier/  and its introduction https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9E0Nn_a6wCs&index=12&list=PLyWdRVpqt5ZdQ6SdPuLQ76nShiuwXu_uC.

Comment: That would be great but in my version of blender fracture modifier isn't  present in physics.

Comment: Nevermind I see that I have to download the modifier. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried rigid bodies? If I understand what you want to do,  this can be done that way.

Comment: I have not yet. I will check it out. I have only used the collision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you are wanting to achieve correctly, this can be accomplished using *rigid body physics*. First you need to have an object suitable to crumble, or shatter, the *cell fracture* addon works well here. 
If you do not have it enabled, then go to user preferences and enable it.

Fracture your object, then add rigid body physics to one cell first. In the (*tool panel* under *physics>add active*) Next, go to the physics tab, and select *enable deactivation* and *start deactivated*.

[image]

It also may be useful to adjust the *friction* settings here as well. Then <kbd>B</kbd> to border select all the fractures and click *copy from active* in the tool panel.

[image]
[image]

Now, select your text and add physics to it. This time click *add passive*.

Lastly, select your bottle and add it's physics which will be *active*. In the physics tab, select **animated.**

[image]

Now you can hide the rock object for now, keyframe the bottle's location at frame one, and it's final location upon resting on the text. When you are done setting your keyframes, unhide everything, and that's it!

I just used a cube and Suzanne for my example, but you will be to achieve these results and more after following these steps. 
[image]

Comment: @BenSmith then you should [mark this as answered](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) ;-)